# Router causing slow internet speeds

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I got a new modem that supports up to 300Mbps, and when I plug my Mac mini directly into the modem, I get speeds of up to 350Mbps. However, when I put my router (Netgear wndr4500), which has 10/100/1000 ports for LAN and WAN, in between them, I am only getting about 100Mbps. I am running DD-WRT on the router as well, but I tried it with the stock router software and the same result occurred.

Note: I tried using different cables as well, all of the Cat5e variety in case that was the issue, with no effect.

Note 2: When I open up the Network Utility on OS X, it says the link speed is 1Gbit/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, and if anyone else comes across this.

I ended up fixing this by removing dd-wrt and reloading the stock firmware on and my speeds went back up to about 280Mbps wired and about 200Mbps wireless.

Just to note, it wasn't exactly the stock firmware that came with the router, but the latest version downloaded from the Netgear site.